# Sort a grid graph by weights

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, grid, networkx

I have a grid graph, whose edges are a list of tuples of tuples, which represents the nodes:

```
G.edges = [((0, 0), (1, 0)), ..., ((15, 14), (15, 15))]
```

Moreover, each element has a weight:

```
G[(0,1)][(0,2)] = {'weight': 0.59}
```

How can a sort G.edges by the weights? I tried many things with `key=lambda`, but nothing has worked so far.

For reproducability, the full code is:

```
from networkx import grid_graph
field_shape = (16, 16)
G = grid_graph(dim=list(field_shape))
edge_weights = np.array([[e, random.rand()] for e in G.edges()]) # shape (nb_edges, 2)
for e, weight in edge_weights:
    G[e[0]][e[1]]['weight'] = weight # Adds weights to all edges ((G[(0,1)][(0,2)]) = {'weight': 0.59})
nodes = [n for n in G.nodes()]
```

Comment: Please provide an example graph with weights in python.

Comment: Yes i just realized, I added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```py
from networkx import grid_graph
import numpy as np
field_shape = (2, 2)
G = grid_graph(dim=list(field_shape))
edge_weights = np.array([[e, np.random.rand()] for e in G.edges()]) # shape (nb_edges, 2)
for e, weight in edge_weights:
    G[e[0]][e[1]]['weight'] = weight # Adds weights to all edges ((G[(0,1)][(0,2)]) = {'weight': 0.59})
nodes = [n for n in G.nodes()]

for edge in G.edges():
    print(f"{edge[0]} -> {edge[1]} = {G[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']}")

print()
sorted_edges = sorted(G.edges(), key=lambda edge: G[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight'])
for edge in sorted_edges:
    print(f"{edge[0]} -> {edge[1]} = {G[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']}")
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) = 0.7516163148696177
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) = 0.25352872203948684
(0, 1) -> (1, 1) = 0.7781608787306042
(1, 0) -> (1, 1) = 0.08342751486451083

(1, 0) -> (1, 1) = 0.08342751486451083
(0, 0) -> (0, 1) = 0.25352872203948684
(0, 0) -> (1, 0) = 0.7516163148696177
(0, 1) -> (1, 1) = 0.7781608787306042
```

Comment: Amazing!!  It worked, I actually tried some very similar things, but just not quite right :)